# Does Tarjan algorithm fail for this test case ? references :gfg and Tushar roy's tutorial

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, tarjans-algorithm

The test case is : 
There are 3 vertices 1,2,3 such

edge: source-destination

```
1-2
1-3
2-3
```

As dfs proceeds from 1 to 2 and then to 3 . 
Following are the discovery and low times :

```
1 discT:0,lowT:0;

2 discT:1,lowT:1;

3 discT:2,lowT:2;
```

Since 2's disc time is less than 3's low time . 2 becomes the articulation point due to the theorem which should NOT BE.

Am i doing something wrong . Kindly explain.
Below is my dfs function->

```
public void dfs(){
             ArrayDeque<vertex> st=new ArrayDeque<>();
             st.push(vertexList.get(0));
             int pt=1;
            vertexList.get(0).discTime=0;
            vertexList.get(0).lowTime=0;
            vertexList.get(0).visited=true;
            int numberOfverticesCovered=0;
             while(!st.isEmpty()){
                 vertex v=st.peek();
                 System.out.println("considering "+v.label);
                 vertex p=getAdjacent(v);
                 if(p==null)
                 {
                     System.out.println("left with no unvisited adjacent vertices "+v.label);
                     if(v!=vertexList.get(0)){
                         LinkedList<edge> le=adjList.get(v.label-1);
                         for (edge e : le)
                         {
                                 if(v.discTime<=e.destination.lowTime)
                                 {
                                    artPoints.add(v);
                                     System.out.println("new articulation point found "+v.label+" for edge "+e.source.label+" and "+e.destination.label);
                                     System.out.println("disc time of "+v.label+"  is "+v.discTime+" and low time is "+v.lowTime);
                                     System.out.println("disc time of adj "+e.destination.label+"  is "+e.destination.discTime+" and low time is "+e.destination.lowTime);
                                    break;
                                 }
                                    v.lowTime=Math.min(v.lowTime, e.destination.lowTime);
                                    System.out.println("new low time of "+v.label+"  is "+v.lowTime);
                         }
                     }
                     numberOfverticesCovered+=1;
                     st.pop();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     v.children+=1;
    //                 System.out.println("adding child "+p.label+" to parent "+v.label);
                     p.discTime=pt;
                     p.lowTime=pt;
                     p.parent=v;
                     st.push(p);
                     pt+=1;
                 }
                 if(st.isEmpty()&& numberOfverticesCovered!=vertexList.size()){
                     for (vertex object : vertexList) {
                         if(!object.visited)
                         {
                             object.discTime=pt;
                             object.lowTime=pt;
                             object.visited=true;
                             st.push(object);
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             if(vertexList.get(0).children>1 ) //  put in check for back edge for the other children so that they are not connected to each other.
             {             
                 artPoints.add(vertexList.get(0));
                 System.out.println("added root as an articulation point and it has "+vertexList.get(0).children);
             }

         } 

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is quite hard to read due to opaque variable naming and lack of structure. Could I suggest you start by breaking the method into several independent methods that implement the various parts of the algorithm and then writing unit tests for those parts? That will allow you to focus your question on the area with the defect.

Comment: @sprinter I have provided code just for reference . My original question was as to why the algorithm detects the articulation point . I have explained the flow of logic in words there. I wanted to ask am I following the algorithm wrong ?